# ERROR: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java, exception

First of all, sorry for being a total noob... I'm trying to train myself by programming a simple calculator in the windows console. But there is this error appearing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 
 0  
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)  
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:711)  
at app.main(app.java:58)
```

I tried many things to change my code and fix the error but I can't see what I did wrong!

I read many answers about this exception but i'm pretty sure that -> choice1 isn't empty before the keyboard entry...

And last thing, I don't use IDE... Only cmd.exe...

Thanks for the help!

Here's the code:

```
    import mypackage.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class app
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice1 = 'y';

    while(choice1 == 'y')
    {
        System.out.print("\nWhich calcul ?\n");
        System.out.print("\n1 Addition | 2 Soustraction | 3 multiplication | 4 Division\n");
        
        int choice2 = sc.nextInt();

        switch(choice2)
        {
            case 1: System.out.print("\nAddition!\n\nEnter the first number:\n");
                    double x = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the second number:\n");
                    double y = sc.nextInt();
                    add addition = new add(x, y);
                    break;

            case 2: System.out.print("\nSoustraction!\n\nEnter the first number:\n");
                    double a = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the second number:\n");
                    double b = sc.nextInt();
                    sous soustraction = new sous(a, b);
                    break;

            case 3: System.out.print("\nMultiplication!\n\nEnter the first number:\n");
                    double c = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the second number:\n");
                    double d = sc.nextInt();
                    mul multiplication = new mul(c, d);
                    break;

            case 4: System.out.print("\nDivision!\n\nEnter the first number:\n");
                    double e = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the second number:\n");
                    double f = sc.nextInt();
                    div division = new div(e, f);
                    break;

            default: System.out.print("\nError, choose a number for operation!\n");
                    break;
        }

        choice1 = ' ';

        while(choice1 != 'y' && choice1 != 'n')
        {
            System.out.print("\nTry again ?\n");
            System.out.print("y | n\n");
            choice1 = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
        };

    };
    
}
```

}

Comment: Try printing out (while debugging) the value of `sc.nextLine ()` by assigning it to a variable, printing it, and then using it to call `charAt`.  Try testing the length of `sc.nextLine ()` before calling `charAt`, looping if length is zero.

Comment: You might copy-paste a command-line session to your question so we can see the input and how it reacts.  Perhaps you pressed the Enter key without a y or n.

Comment: `sc.nextLine().trim().charAt(0);`?

Comment: @Darkman Yes it works!! I might have to look at this method (trim()), interesting... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using sc.nextLine() instead of sc.next(). The next() method returns the next inputed value, while the nextLine() method skips a line and returns the input. Swapping the nextLine() method with the next() method should fix the error

Comment: Wow it works too, thanks a lot for your answer and for the explanations!